# ayuda a leer archivo excel en java

Tags: java, apache-poi

necesito almacenar la información de un archivo xls, en un arraylist, obteniendo sus columnas una a una, actualmente logro obtener toda la información del archivo, pero no tengo idea como guardar cada fila en un arraylist, actualmente esto es lo que tengo

formato del archivo xls

```
rut carrera_id  Seccion       Fecha_I
11  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   12-10-2017
11  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   19-10-2017
22  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   12-10-2017
22  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   19-10-2017
22  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   26-10-2017
23  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   12-10-2017
23  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   19-10-2017
24  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   12-10-2017
25  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   12-10-2017
25  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   19-10-2017
25  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   26-10-2017
25  14460-03    DEJ4501-001   15-10-2017
```

clase que da formato para el arraylist

```
public class Formato {
 String rut, carrera, seccion, fecha;

    public Formato() {
    }

    public Formato(String rut, String carrera, String seccion, String fecha) {
        this.rut = rut;
        this.carrera = carrera;
        this.seccion = seccion;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getRut() {
        return rut;
    }

    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }

    public String getCarrera() {
        return carrera;
    }

    public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
        this.carrera = carrera;
    }

    public String getSeccion() {
        return seccion;
    }

    public void setSeccion(String seccion) {
        this.seccion = seccion;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
```

metodo donde leo el archivo xls, y donde debo guardar cada fila en el arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try{
        FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\javie\\Desktop\\ReporteInasistencias2017_2.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        ArrayList<Formato> storage=new ArrayList();

        FormulaEvaluator eva=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        for(Row row: sheet){
            for(Cell cell:row){
                switch(eva.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()){
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t\t");
                            break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("ruta incorrecta");
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("error al leer el archivo");
    }
```

necesito guardar cada fila en el arraylist storage, espero puedan ayudarme

---

**Update**

actualmente logre guardar todas las colummnas, pero con algo no muy ortodoxo, necesito que me ayuden a mejorar el codigo, actualmente tengo esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try{
        FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\javie\\Desktop\\ReporteInasistencias2017_2.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);

        FormulaEvaluator eva=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        ArrayList<String> rut=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> carrera=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> seccion=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> fecha=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Formato> excelArray=new ArrayList();

        for (int j=0; j< sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; j++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0); 
        rut.add(cell.toString());
        }

        for (int j=0; j< sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; j++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(1); 
        carrera.add(cell.toString());
        }

        for (int j=0; j< sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; j++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(2); 
        seccion.add(cell.toString());
        }

        for (int j=0; j< sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; j++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
        fecha.add(cell.toString());
        }


        for(int i=1;i<rut.size();i++){
            Formato ft=new Formato();
            ft.setRut(rut.get(i));
            ft.setCarrera(carrera.get(i));
            ft.setSeccion(seccion.get(i));
            ft.setFecha(fecha.get(i));
            excelArray.add(ft);

            System.out.println("rut del alummno: "+ft.getRut()+", carrera del alummno: "+ft.getCarrera()+", seccion del Alummno: "+ft.getSeccion()+", fecha de inasistencia: "+ft.getFecha());

        }
        System.out.println("arreglo: "+excelArray.size());
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

    }catch(IOException e){

    }

  }
```

actualmente funciona todo correcto, pero quiero optimizar todos esos for

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? o ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Necesito almacenar las filas en un arraylist y no se como, cree una clase con el formato del archivo excel, pero nose como hacer que se almacene

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Dentro de los for he estado haciendo algo, pero se me cae la app, ya que la idea es crear un objeto formato y asiganarle valores mediante el actual indice, pero sinceramente no he podido

Comment: actualize mi pregunta, con nuevo codigo